# In Java StreamTokenizer docs, what does "ordinary" mean?

Tags: java, parsing, token, tokenize

I'm trying to understand how to use StreamTokenizer. I don't understand the difference between `wordChars` and `ordinaryChars`. What is the difference between this two methods? What 'ordinary' means?

Answer (score 0):

Ordinary means that the char is a 'structural' char of a code, e.g. for JSON the 'ordinary' chars are '{', '}', '[', ']', ':', ','.

This chars are used in StreamTokenizer as separated token and when it is found, the value on StreamTokenizer.sval is not update instead of StreamTokenizer.ttype is update.